# Filter dataframe based on row number

Tags: python, pandas

Here I am filtering the dataframe based on row number. But I am getting only the record of index1 and index last. Please help me!

I have tried following code

```
n3.iloc[[1, 1000], 0]

#also this
n3.iloc[[1, 1000], :]

#also by using isin
n3[n3.index.isin([1,50])]

but getting same output as first, only two record.
```

[image]

Comment: cant you just do sth like `n3[1:50]`

Comment: Hey @oskros , thanks! its wroking

Answer (score 1):

As `oskros` mentioned in the comments you can just do `n3[1:50]`.

In this answer I will try to explain why your other attempts don't work with examples.

```
import pandas as pd

# Example value of n3 for demo purposes
n3 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1000 for _ in range(10000)]})

>>> n3.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10000, step=1)
```

So `n3.index` in this example is a type of Pandas Index (`RangeIndex`) that starts at `0`, stops at `10000` and increments with one every time.

The documentation says the following on [`pandas.Index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html)

> Compute boolean array of whether each index value is found in the passed set of values. The length of the returned boolean array matches the length of the index.

So when you do this

```
>>> n3[n3.index.isin([1,50])]
       A
1   1000
50  1000
```

You're actually saying something like: For each index value determine if it exists in the set passed as an input to `isin`. Since you're passing `[1,50]` this matches the index where the index is `1` or where it is `50`. Two numbers that match the index values means you are left with two rows after filtering `n3`.

The other examples listed in your question using `iloc` do about the same.